# c++ weird characters appear while writing to a file

Tags: c++

When i run this code, and open the .dat file in notepad/wordpad it shows some weird characters

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class Student
{
    int rollno;
    char name[20];
    char div[20];
public:
    void accept()
    {
        cout<<"enter rollno"<<endl;
        cin>>rollno;
        cout<<"Enter name"<<endl;
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter div"<<endl;
        cin>>div;
    }
    void write_rec()
    {
        ofstream f;
        f.open("Student.dat",ios::binary|ios::app);
        Student s;
        s.accept();
        f.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
        f.close();
    }
    void display()
    {
        ifstream f;
        Student s;
        f.open("Student.dat",ios::binary|ios::in);
        while(f.read((char*)&s,sizeof(s)))
            s.show();
        f.close();
    }
    void show()
    {
        cout<<rollno<<endl;
        cout<<name<<endl;
        cout<<div<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Student s;
    s.write_rec();
    s.display();

}
```

The code is getting compiled and run perfectly but when i open the "Student.dat" file it shows some weird characters

Comment: It's perfectly natural to expect some "weird characters" when you open a *binary* file with a *text* editor.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
    f.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
```

Is writing the raw binary bytes of your Student object into the file.  If that's not the behavior you intended, you'll need to do something else, e.g. translate the member fields of your Student object (in particular the `rollno` variable, which is an `int`) into ASCII text strings and write those strings into the file instead.

Answer (score 0):

on both places when you open file:

```
    f.open("Student.dat",ios::binary|ios::app);
```

and:

```
    f.open("Student.dat",ios::binary|ios::in);
```

you open as binary. try to remove this option.

as you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode), these are platform specific behaviors.

take a look at [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream)

EDIT:

and, of course, as Jeremy observed, you have to write meaningful text to your file. on this line:

```
    f.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
```

you are actually writing each byte (as (char*)) of your object. if you understand what you're doing, and that's what you want to observe, than ok. but maybe you should compare both outputs, from this method and from Jeremy's suggestion.